# Hibernate - retrying failed update because of StaleObjectStateException still tries to save the stale instance

Tags: hibernate, optimistic-locking

I am having trouble with hibernate and versioning. I am using Hibernate 3.6.7-Final. Here is a code snippet from my DAO class (it is called by Spring Beans that use the @Transactional annotations, so it is not transactional itself, but to force the StaleObjectStateException, a flush is used):

```
@Override
public void save(User user) {
    boolean saved = false;
    while (!saved) {
        try {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(user);
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
            saved = true;
        } catch (StaleObjectStateException exc) {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().refresh(user);
        }
    }
}
```

The version is a long value mapped like this:

```
<version name="version" access="field" column="version" type="long" unsaved-value="null" />
```

The problem is, that the user is never saved, and the code just loops forever. I debugged a little and it turns out that hibernate has a concept of an ActionQueue, and inside, it has inserts, updates and so on in separate collections. With every loop of the code above, the update collection grows by 1. It fails as it always tries to execute the update at index 0 in that collection, which is the 'stale' one, and fails at that point, and doesn't try to perform the update with the refreshed version. Is there a way I can make this work?

Maybe some background about what I want to do, so maybe someone smarter will be able to suggest a better solution: suppose there is no versioning, and the user has a column that contains the invalid login count. This count grows by one with each failure, and gets reset with a successful login. (We use it to introduce a timeout as to when the user can login after x unsuccessful attempts, so as to prevent a brute force on the accounts, but this is irrelevant here.) Now, suppose the attacker uses an attack, in which the same user account can be accessed by multiple threads on the server, and when 2 threads read the user with the failure count, say, 2, then thread 1 updates it to 3, saves, then thread 2 updates it to 3, and saves - we just lost one unsuccessful attempt, which is a bug.

So, in order to fix this, I wanted to introduce the versioning column, that would in this case serve no other purpose as to cause throwing an exception by thread 2 above, in which case, the operation would be retried (potentially, but highly unlikely, in a loop) - basically, this would introduce serialization of saving the users, but based on optimistic locking. This, as stated before, doesn't work.

Can anybody help me out with this? Is this a good idea to start with? Maybe there is a better way? Why does the Hibernate snippet doesn't work?

Comment: are you testing the code above with one thread?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a new session to execute the update.
As a general rule, you shouldn't use a session after an exception was raised.

You can read [this](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=942461) thread for more info.
TL;DR:
Exceptions thrown by hibernate are not recoverable. You have to rollback, close your session and start again.